# How would I insert a boolean value in postgresql through python?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have to write a piece of code. A moderator is supposed to pull the latest message from a database and accept it or reject it (Suitable for online view). Row 'acceptreject' is the bool. I just have no idea where to start. So far I've figured out how to view the newest unmoderated message only:

````
cur.execute(```SELECT (name, message, date, time) WHERE acceptreject is NULL SORT BY time DESC LIMIT 1```)
````

But how to actually add a value to ONLY this message and then automatically showing the next one is quite a mystery to me.

Anyone here to help? Thanks!

Comment: yo can add column of statuses for message. so if status not moderated show...

Comment: Unrelated, but: do **not** enclose the column list with parentheses. You are creating a **single** column using that syntax. It creates an anonymous record type with three fields in it which is then returned as a single column. This is most likely not what you want.

Comment: Is this really how you formatted the string?  '```' is not proper for quoting the string or did you just misplace the SO code formatting back ticks? Also you are missing the `FROM` for the table. Please update your question with a complete accurate query.  To update this message you will need to include the `PRIMARY KEY` in the `SELECT` and then use that to do the `"UPDATE <table_name> SET acceptreject = 't' WHERE pk = <pk_value>;"`  or `'f'` for false.

Comment: Alternate method: `cur.execute("UPDATE <table_name> SET acceptreject = %s WHERE pk = <pk_value>", [True] )`. See [Type adaptation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types) for more information.